# Why show "Edit" option for comments that are more than 5 minutes old?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, edits

To my surprise I was not able to find a thread for the same request. If I missed it, please point me into the right direction.

Though it's probably a low priority I would like to mention it nevertheless.

We are allowed to edit our `comments` to questions and answers only for 5 minutes after posting them.  This is quite OK with me.

Why then even show an `Edit` option after that time?  Is it just so we can view/copy full comment? If so, then may be it would be a good idea to replace `Edit` with `View` in such situation and remove the `Save` option?

Comment: When you refresh the page after 5 mintes, the edit option will be gone.

Comment: Yes, I read it. But how often we refresh the screen while still busy with the question?

Answer (score 2):

Presumably the timer that determines whether you can edit or not is on the server-side at StackExchange. So the options are either

1. to change the Edit link after 5 minutes using a client-side timer that may not match the server-side one, or
2. poll the server to see if editing is still allowed.

Neither one seems to me like the best use of resources, given that comments are considered to be "second class citizens".

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty much what I was going to say.  Programming is an exercise in tradeoffs; you have to pick your battles.

Comment: SO does has to get the time on `Save` anyway.  Programmers can considerably make such a call earlier and set a flag.  Since time does not go backwards, this flag would be valid for later use as well.  So this will not increase server or client load.  Ana yes, I said upfront that this is a low priority issue.